# Alt key interrups the GUI

Tags: java

I currently have a very simple game, where you move a black rectangle from side to side using the arrows keys. My problem is that whenever the alt key is being pressed (mostly by accident), the game window loses focus and doesn't reply to the arrow keys anymore. The focus is regained if I press alt again, but if the rectangle is already in motion it will keep going non stop.
I'm using these render and update methods btw.

Is there a way to prevent the alt key from doing its job - focusing on the UI's menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to prevent the alt key from doing its job - focusing on the UI's menu?

Strictly speaking, no - or more to the point, that's the wrong approach.

What you should be doing is using the [Key Bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which will overcome the focus related issues of `KeyListener`, this way, you don't "have" to care

This is a really simple test which binds actions to the <kbd>ALT</kbd> and other keys and seems to work for me, but immediately, I'm testing on MacOS.  I also found that you can only bind to the "key released" event of the meta keys

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");

                JMenuBar mb= new JMenuBar();
                JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
                menu.add("This is test item");
                mb.add(menu);
                frame.setJMenuBar(mb);

                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

            private JLabel label;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            label = new JLabel("...");
            add(label);

            InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0), "A");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0), "W");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0), "S");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0), "D");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ALT, 0, true), "ALT");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL, 0, true), "CTRL");
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_META, 0, true), "META");

            ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();
            actionMap.put("A", new TextAction("A"));
            actionMap.put("W", new TextAction("W"));
            actionMap.put("S", new TextAction("S"));
            actionMap.put("D", new TextAction("D"));
            actionMap.put("ALT", new TextAction("ALT"));
            actionMap.put("CTRL", new TextAction("CTRL"));
            actionMap.put("META", new TextAction("META"));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected class TextAction extends AbstractAction {
            private String text;

            public TextAction(String text) {
                this.text = text;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                label.setText(text);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

As an alternative, you could also look at `KeyboardFocusManager.addKeyEventDispatcher` and/or `Toolkit.addAWTEventListener` to see if you can determine when the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key is pressed and either force focus back to the component OR, better, pause the game - as there might be a legitimate reason the user wants access to the system menu.

To that end, a `FocusListener` might be a simpler solution all round, as you can simply determine when focus is lost or gained and pause/resume the game appropriately

Comment: On Windows even key bindings don't work. I have bindings using the WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW InputMap and when the Alt key is pressed focus goes to the system menu and the bindings stop working. I need to press Alt a second time before the bindings work. I didn't test if you can add a KeyBinding for the Alt key to prevent focus going to the System menu.

Comment: @camickr I was thinking more along the lines of the `JMenu` API

Comment: In Windows even if you have a JMenuBar when you press Alt, focus goes to the system menu (not the menu bar). I agree, that key bindings will solve most focus issues, but I'm suggesting that the OS is handling key events, not Swing, so not even key bindings will work here, unless there is some way to intercept the Alt key in Swing before the OS handles it.

Comment: @camickr Yeah, I'm following your point - but since I no longer Windows, it's one of those hard to test edge cases. `KeyboardFocusManager.addKeyEventDispatcher` or `Toolkit.addAWTEventListener` *might* work, assuming the OS isn't consuming the key stroke before the event queue has a chance to process it.  Interestingly, during my testing, I could only get a "on key release" binding to work for alt, control and command/meta

Comment: (1+) Works on Windows as well.